# ISIN with at least 1 number

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx to parse ISIN of bonds, assets, etc.. (2 characters followed by 10 digits and characters)

```
([A-Z]{2})([A-Z0-9]{10})
```

But this also marks for example a word like this `ABCDEFGHIJKL`, but this is no real ISIN. A definition of ISINs is here: [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number)

So some examples are `US45256BAD38`, `US64118Q1076`, `XS0884410019`. What would be the correct RegEx to search for them, without matches like `ABCDEFGHIJKL`?

Maybe with a RegEx to have at least one number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookahead regex:

```
\b([A-Z]{2})((?![A-Z]{10}\b)[A-Z0-9]{10})\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI9hN9/1)

`(?![A-Z]{10}\b)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if all 10 chars are letters after first 2 chars.

Comment: Thanks! This works fine in the demo, but I use it in PLSQL with REGEXP_SUBSTR and there it fails.. do you know if REGEXP_SUBSTR does not support lookaheads?

Comment: Hmm you didn't mention this in question. I'm not sure if Oracle regex supports lookahead. Check documentation.

Comment: Yes I thought that this would be no problem for Oracle, but in fact Oracle doesn't support lookahead and lookbehind. You answered my question so thanks! I just asked the wrong question

Comment: The regex does what it says, but is incorrect for determining valid ISIN values.

Comment: @enharmonic: This answer just addresses the problem that OP is facing, nothing more was attempted.

Answer (score 18):

If you can not use lookahead according to the Wikipedia defintion you can also just check if the last character is a number as it should be the check digit.

> ISINs consist of two alphabetic characters, which are the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code for the issuing country, nine alpha-numeric characters (the National Securities Identifying Number, or NSIN, which identifies the security, padded as necessary with leading zeros), and **one numerical check digit**.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number#Description

Meaning this also could work:

```
([A-Z]{2})([A-Z0-9]{9})([0-9]{1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget the ^$ signs to avoid accepting longer strings like 'something_AS1234567890_anything_else'

`^([A-Z]{2})([A-Z0-9]{9})([0-9]{1})$`