# Extracting ISIN, Cusip and other patterns from text in Python

Tags: python

An ISIN code, or international securities identification number, is a 12 digit code consisting of numbers and letters that distinctly identify securities.

An example of an ISIN is: LU1234567890

If I have a long text string, how can I detect an ISIN-pattern and extract all the isins from it in Python?

Comment: You could use some sort of regular expression but need to clarify tha actual format.

Comment: 2 letters followed by 10 numbers. How would that work?

Comment: Is the format of ISIN two letters and ten numbers? 123456789012 and ABCDE1234567 are not ISIN?

Comment: Correct @GilseungAhn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\d{10}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/u88zZz/1).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

for number in re.finditer(r'\b[A-Z]{2}\d{10}\b', your_actual_string):
    print(number.group(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Regular Expressions module, it is specific for that. Here's the doc:
https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html

Comment: That is to extract a pattern, but a 2 digit followed by 10 numbers is quite a specific pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use string method `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` as follows.

```
def find_ISIN(S):
    ISIN_list = []
    for i in range(len(S) - 12):
        if S[i:i+2].isalpha() and S[i+2:i+12].isdigit():
            ISIN_list.append(S[i:i+12])    
    return ISIN_list
```

Code test.

```
S = 'LU1234567890-SU1234567890f$3121'
print(find_ISIN(S))
```

The output is `['LU1234567890', 'SU1234567890']`.

**Edit.** If S[i:i+12] is ISIN format, then S[i+k:i+k+12] for 1<=k<=11 cannot be ISIN. Thus, I edited the code to avoid to find S[i+k:i+k+12].

```
def find_ISIN(S):
    ISIN_list = []
    i = 0
    while i <= len(S) - 12:
        if S[i:i+2].isalpha() and S[i+2:i+12].isdigit():
            ISIN_list.append(S[i:i+12])
            i += 12
        else:
            i += 1
    return ISIN_list
```

Answer (score 1):

ISIN format is defined by ISO 6166. The last character is a [single check digit](https://www.isin.org/isin-format/). So regex is not enough in theory.

One option is to iterate on all 12 character `[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{9}[0-9]`sequences and verify the checksum. In any normal text, that should be enough.

```
 for isin in re.findall(isin_regex, text):
     If check_isin(isin):
         print('ISIN found: %s' % isin)
```

One could even argue that the probability of a wrong ISIN in a common text is very small and we could do without the check.

For the sake of the discussion, assuming the text is any sequence of data, `re.findall` is no longer an option because it only finds non overlapping sequences. Which means a wrong ISIN could hide a real one. This question has already been [answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches).

If performance is an issue and you are in a complex case, it should be possible to implement a DFA like algorithm to find them in near linear complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions with:

```
import re
```

And a query  similar to laid out here:

[RegEx for ISIN with at least 1 number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164718/regex-for-isin-with-at-least-1-number)

If you string has a **very** large number of consecutive 12 character/digit combinations that look like ISINs and would be erroneously picked up by a naive parser, an option would be to downloaded list of all ISINs/CUSIPs/etc, throw them in a hash table and use this as a relatively quick additional filter.